# Form Builder - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined, issue with validators

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular6, formbuilder

I have a Form Builder form in my Angular 6 project, and I'm getting an issue with the validators.

I think I know what the issue is, but don't know how to fix it.
I have a custom validator (not really custom, I use min() and max() with a custom variable for the check)

And probably the form is initialized before those values.

The form is declared before the constructor (I tried moving it into the construction and into ngOnInit, same result)

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
        title: [""],
        date: [""],
        max_score: [, [Validators.required, Validators.max(6), Validators.min(1)]],
        min_score: [, [Validators.required, Validators.max(6), Validators.min(1)]]
});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

Like this everything works, even the validators.
The `max_score` and `min_score` are 2 dropdowns, where you can choose a number.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
max_score: [, [Validators.required, Validators.max(6), Validators.min(this.myForm.get("min_points").value)]],
min_score: [, [Validators.required, Validators.max(this.myForm.get("max_score").value), Validators.min(1)]]
```

So basically the `max_score` cannot be lower than the `min_score`, and the `min_score` cannot be higher than the `max_score`!

But this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

So I guess that's because `this.myForm.get("max_score").value` is not accessible when the Form builder is initialized.

How can I solve this? Those values are optional in my form, so it's correct that they have no value at the start, and I just want to put in place a check that avoids that a min_value is chosen that is higher than the max_value

I even tried put the this.myForm.get.... in a function:

```
getMaxPoints(): number {
        if (this.myForm.get("max_score").value) {
            return this.myForm.get("max_score").value;
        } else return null;
    }
```

and then

```
 min_score: [, [Validators.required, Validators.max(this.getMaxPoints()), Validators.min(1)]]
```

but I get the same error!

What's the workaround for this issue?

Comment: is not this be `max_score` instead of `this.myForm.get("max_points").value)` same goes to the `min_points` as well

Comment: sorry that was just a typo here on stackoverflow, in my code it's max_score everywhere! so that's not it

Answer (score 0):

When you create a form, you pass values to the validators array, values that are passed only at creation time.

So if you use an expression like

```
Validators.max(this.myForm.get("max_points").value)
```

you are evaluating during the creation of the form. So `myForm` variable is still undefined.

Try using some variables instead of accessing `myForm` properties like this:

```
minVal: number = 5;
maxVal: number = 5;

max_score: [, [Validators.required, Validators.max(6), Validators.min(minVal)]],
min_score: [, [Validators.required, Validators.max(maxVal), Validators.min(1)]]
```

To validate data getting some parameters from the form you should use the extra from `this.fb.group()`

You can try something like this:

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
        title: [""],
        date: [""],
        max_score: [, [Validators.required]],
        min_score: [, [Validators.required]]
},
{
       // THIS IS EXTRA!!!!!
       validator: [customValidator()]
});
```

This is an example of `customValidator`:

```
export function customValidator() {
  return (group: FormGroup) => {
    const minScore = group.controls['min_score'],
      maxScore = group.controls['max_core'],
      minPoints = group.controls['min_points'];

    if (/** some condition **/) {
      return minPoints.setErrors({'notMatching': true});
    } else {
      return minPoints.setErrors(null);
    }
  };
}
```

Note that into `customValidator` you are accessing `myForm` data dynamically accessing its controls.

Then in your template you need to show errors depending on

```
<div *ngIf="f.min_points.errors && f.min_points.errors.notMatching">NOT VALID</div>
```

I don't remember if is available a `notMatching` error, but you can print all available errors with

```
<pre>{{ f.min_points.errors | json }</pre>
```

where `f` is a convenience getter method like this:

```
 get f() {
    return this.myForm.controls;
  }
```

Comment: yes I get that, this is why I tried to use a function instead:

getMaxScore(): number {
  if (this.myForm.get("max_score").value) {
   return this.detailsForm.get("max_score").value;
  } else return 6;
 }

so if myForm is still undefined, it will return a number "6", so the validator will have a value, but it doesn't work, I get the same error, this time on the line of the function I created, so how can I just have a validator some how that doesn't allow my min_score to be higher than my max_score, and vice versa

Comment: yeah but in your function you are accessing still myForm, so it is still undefined :)

Comment: yes I know, but how can I solve this then? eventually I need to access those values in myForm to validate the value and check if min_score < max_score, what s the other solution then?

Comment: ok, what about if I do it like you did, with minVal and maxVal to initialize, then I use myForm.get("max_score").valueChanges and subscribe to it on the ngOnInit, so when a change is done there, I do: maxVal = myForm.get("max_score").value

Comment: let's try my new solution

Comment: I'll try it in a sec, meanwhile I tried the solution I wrote in the upper comment, minVal and maxVal change dynamically when subscribed to the changes, but the validator just doesn't work, I can put a min value higher than a max, and the validator won't kick in

Comment: validators params are static. they will have always the same value

Comment: ah ok, implementing your solution right now, can I ask you what's minPoints for?

Comment: mmm maybe I have added it by mistake. however the point is that you can access all myForm field by this way

Comment: customValidator(): any {
  return (group: FormGroup) => {
   const minScore = group.controls["min_score"],
    maxScore = group.controls["max_score"];

   if (minScore > maxScore) {
    return minScore.setErrors({notMatching: true});
   } else {
    return (minScore.setErrors(null));
   }
  };
 }

I did this, added the validators in the Form Builder as your example, I get no errors but the validator just doesn't work! I can put a min_score higher than a max_score, and I won't get a red underline in my dropdown (which happens if I put fixed values in the validators, like 1 and 6)

Comment: I can't try it now, that is only an example. if you debug the execution is right?

Comment: obviously in your template you need to manage errorm in this case `notMatching` error

Comment: oh ok didn't change anyhting in the templace, what s the correct syntax? I guess I'll have to create a <div> with a ngIf ? and inside the div a string containing something like: The value must be higher than the max grade
Going off now, gonna try tomorrow and mark your answer as good, as I bet this is going to work! thank you

Comment: in your example, what's F?

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
public myForm:FormGroup; // you should do this
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
     this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        title: [''],
        date: [''],
        max_score: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(6), Validators.min(1)]],
        min_score: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(6), Validators.min(1)]]
     });
}
```

and access it:

```
this.myForm.get("max_score").value
```

or:

```
this.myForm.controls["max_score"].value
```

Comment: I fail to see in what it resolve the OP's problem to make sure than min is < max.

Comment: the only thing that changed in your solution is that you moved my initialization of the Formbuilder into the constructor!!

Doesn't change anything, I tried moving it in the constructor and in NgOnInit, same error

Comment: @AJ989 you get the undefined error so you are doing wrong definition of form you can try this then say it helps or not, also check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo06-reactive-forms-custom-validation-xjhr3m)

Comment: @fatemefazli I did try it, I declared the myForm variable, and initialized it in the constructor, then I also tried using the other version, this.myForm.controls[...]
But I get the same error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Comment: And ofc In the declaration of the form, where the validators are, I didn't leave: Validators.max(6), that works of course, as I wrote in my OP, I put the this.myForm.get("max_score").value there, and it gives errror

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `(keyup)="checkMinMax()"` in your html both on min and max. In the checkMinMax function you can check the contents of `this.myForm.get("max_score").value` and `this.myForm.get("min_score").value` either show a message with *ngIf like you mentioned in your comment or force the min or max value to be the same with the other if the user's input exceeds it. ( or both ).

Additionally by doing this you can just use the required validator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have simple workaround for this problem.  It's a timing issue.  I made it work by defining the member variable as static. My code like below:

```
static numberOfVerses: number;
..
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    suraID: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    bVerseID: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    eVerseID: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    translatorID1: new FormControl(''),
  },validate);

// reference the static variable in the custom validation
validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {

    const suraID = control.get('suraID');
    const bVerseID = control.get('bVerseID');
    const eVerseID = control.get('eVerseID');
    const translatorID1 = control.get('translatorID1');


    if (suraID && bVerseID && eVerseID && QuranSearchComponent.numberOfVerses) {
      if (bVerseID.value > QuranSearchComponent.numberOfVerses || eVerseID.value > QuranSearchComponent.numberOfVerses) {
        return { 'invalid_verse_number': true };
      }
    }

    if (suraID && bVerseID && eVerseID && translatorID1 &&
        bVerseID.value > eVerseID.value) {

        return { 'invalid_verse_range': true };
    }
    return null;
  }
```